# Java - How can I change the color of the app tab?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I change the color of the tab title background? The standard color is blue.  How can I change it to white? Like here: https://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/nexus2cee_43.png

Comment: You asking for browser or app actionbar?

Comment: Im asking for titlebar color, like here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/title-bar-colour-for-an-ionic-2-app-when-viewing-it-among-the-list-of-background-apps-in-android/70473

Answer (score 1):

Customize the default theme

For example, your styles.xml file should look similar to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Once you know your colors, update the values in res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <!--   color for the app bar and other primary UI elements -->
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>

        <!--   a darker variant of the primary color, used for
               the status bar (on Android 5.0+) and contextual app bars -->
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>

        <!--   a secondary color for controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
  </resources>
```

override whatever other styles you want

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/activityBackground</item>
</style>
```

Cited from:  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html#CustomizeTheme

Programatically:

You can call method and set the Theme in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
android:name=".Class.App"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_test"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" <-- Add your custom theme here
</application>
```

Comment: yes it is, but is their any way to make this with java without html?

Comment: See this if it helps